# How kafka connector works with memory leaks?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I launch the kafka connect image . i configured near 25 running source and sink connectors
when i drop inside this container i saw only 1 java processes

```
root@connect:/# ps -ef | grep java
root         1     0  3 Jun20 ?        01:32:06 java -Xms256M -Xmx2G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties -cp /etc/kafka-connect/jars/*:/usr/share/java/kafka/*:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/*:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/*:/usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-support-metrics/*:/usr/share/java/confluent-support-metrics/* org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed /etc/kafka-connect/kafka-connect.properties
root      6263  6252  0 08:58 pts/1    00:00:00 grep java
root@connect:/#
```

Does it means that when we  have a memory leak in one running custom connector it will crash  kafka connect node ?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple threads run in a single JVM. But, sure if you get OOM on only one connect task, then it'll blow the JVM, which is why you should add more servers (since you're running distributed mode) and increase the heap from only 2G max by setting `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`

Also, if running the container, a typical pattern might be one container per topic grouping. For example, 5 topics are going to Elasticsearch, 2 others going to HDFS, and 4 others to JDBC, etc. Would make 3 separate containers. That way your "blast radius" is smaller for a failed java process

If you're using the Confluent containers, set `CONNECT_GROUP_ID` to be the same for a set of containers, also make sure each grouping you make has its own config, offset, and status topics

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do u know how kafka connect cluster communicates between each other ?

Comment: Via a Kafka Consumer group

Comment: distributed connect workers communicate via kafka topics.   In the example  connect-distributed.properties file shipped with Confluent distribution the default is that they share the topics connect-configs, connect-offsets, and connect-statuses (or something very similar)